# How to convince Eclipse to locate neighbor-modules' schema-files?

Tags: eclipse

We are developing a multi-module project. It's setup re. schema files is like so:

```
* module1
| +-- schema1.xsd
| +... more stuff here
* module2
| +-- schema2.xsd
| +... more stuff here
* module3
| +-- schema3.xsd
| +... more stuff here
```

There is one base module (here, say, `module1`) whose schema file is referenced by the schema files of the other modules.

My colleagues - using IntelliJ - wrote these references in `schema2.xsd` and `schema3.xsd` like so:

```
    <xs:import namespace="https://foo.bar/module1/schema1.xsd" />
```

When I import that project into Eclipse, eclipse will wiggle all references to types that are in module1 as faulty because it does not find a suitable .xsd-file for module1. Only after I added an explicit schema location like so:

```
    <xs:import namespace="https://foo.bar/module1/schema1.xsd" schemaLocation="../module1/schema1.xsd" />
```

the schema files validated OK.

Frankly, *I* find that the cleaner behavior because here it becomes explicit which schema file one refers to and one doesn't rely on "some magic" that happens to locate a fitting schema file (which may or may not be the schema one had in mind). Esp. when - in a later, much more complicated setup - there might be *two* or more schema files in different modules with the same name. Which one would it pick then?

My colleagues argue that the relative location of these modules might also change when the project grows and then one would have to adjust these paths. Furthermore, these schema files get shipped with the final application (for runtime schema validation of messages) and in the runtime all schema-files end up in the same resource directory. Here these relative locations might (or will) then not work (though we didn't test that). We would probably need to maintain the directory hierarchy of the original source setup.

That latter argument convinced me. Thus my question:

Is there a way to teach Eclipse to mimic IntelliJ's behavior and locate a suitable schema automatically in sibling modules (i.e. projects) without an explicit `schemaLocation="..."` clause?

Answer (score 0):

Try the XML Catalog preference page.

Comment: This looked very promising at first (I hadn't been aware of that settings page before) and I defined the missing schema under "User Defined Entries" (with key type "SchemaLocation") but unfortunately this had no effect at all. I still get errors that the corresponding name space can not be resolved. :-( What am i missing?

Comment: I also tried with key type "Namespace name" but no difference.